# Details explanation for SpecialCells(xlFormulas) and SpecialCells(xlConstants)

Tags: excel, vba

I encounter the following codes when google some sample code online, but I could not understand the function of them, even after I have checking some related topic, I cant fully understand them, can anyone give some specific explanation and effect when using them and when should i use them?

```
   SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
   SpecialCells(xlConstants)
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx)?

Comment: You are being a bit vague here. What about the references are complicated? I can see in @PankajJaju's link the entirety of its usage, though no doubt a bit lacking in *intensive* delving. :)

Comment: sorry for being vague here, i need like an example including screen shot as below to fully understand the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of answering your question, here are two codes:

```
Sub SelectFormulas()
    Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Select
End Sub

Sub SelectConstants()
    Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
End Sub
```

And here is my set-up (formulas are forced-visible by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>~</kbd> on Column A):

[image]

When I run the `SelectFormulas` macro, it will select all the `SpecialCells` of `xlCellTypeFormulas`. Basically, all cells with formulas in Column A.

Result A:

[image]

When I run the `SelectConstants` macro, then it selects "hard-values". Basically, exactly that: *constants*.

Result B:

[image]

The complete list of each `SpecialCell` type is exactly what they are in [this MSDN nugget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx). You can try experimenting with cells with data validation, or with formats, or blanks. The list goes on.

Let us know if this helps. ;)